# How can I use an already defined variable reference in definition of another variable in shell script/

Tags: shell-script, variable, variable-substitution

I am trying to do something like below :

```
export a="ABC"  # Works fine
export b_"$a"="DEF"  # Works fine
```

**Now how do I print or echo the new variable "`b_$a`" ??**

I tried :

- `echo ${b_$a}`
- `echo ${b_"$a"}`

etc, and many more combinations like this. But none of them is working.

All I am getting is the error :

```
-bash: ${b_$a}: bad substitution
```

Any idea, how can I achieve this ?

Comment: In Bash, use a nameref: `declare -n ref=b_ABC; ref=DEF; echo "$ref"`  (or indirect expansion with `${!varname}`)

Comment: The variables "a" and b_"$a" are calculated variables, can you give me something like :

echo <syntax to print the variable> 
??